# Eclipse Blocking Console View

Tags: eclipse, view

Using Eclipse 3.7.1.r37, I have the "Console" view on the *"[Fast View Bar](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-3a.htm)"* and the view has the *"Horizontal"* orientation applied.

The view undesirably covers the whole area while it's not even maximized and it doesn't provide any means to be resized vertically (The "up-down cursor" doesn't appear on the edge!!) In other words, When you "maximize" or "restore" the view, it doesn't change size and remains covering the whole area.

It's really annoying, as I have to "minimize" the "Console" view to interact with the editor every time I'm done with the debugging; since it covers the whole area :(

The other views also have the *"Horizontal"* orientation in which they can be *freely resized vertically*, except for the *"Console"* view that covers the whole editor area.

How do I overcome the issue to be able to resize the "Console" view not to cover the whole area?

[image: The issue is depicted here.]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you possibly add a picture of what you're describing?  ... I don't have a good "picture" of the issue.

Comment: Are you sure, you are using Eclipse 3.7 which has been release 2011? The current version is Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a). In Oxygen.1a, if the view is opened and you switch between _Vertical_ and _Horizontal_, the view will cover the whole area (seems to be bug: please report it to Eclipse). As workaround, click on the view icon in the _Fast View Bar_ twice to close it and reopen it again.

Comment: @PaulT. Thanks for the reply :) I've updated the OP with a picture :)

Comment: @howlger Thanks for the reply :) Yes, I use v3.7.1, (I know, it's a bit outdated ;) As another workaround I can dock the view somewhere else, but then I will lose the features of _fast view_ :( I'm pretty sure it's a bug! but don't know what causes it nor how to work around it!

Comment: @goodUser What prevents you from updating? What happens if you click on _Size_? Did you already try to reset the whole perspective?

Comment: @howlger Actually some components prohibit me from updating! When I click on the _size_ it lets me decide to position or dock the view somewhere else. I use the _"perspective reset"_ as the last resort actually :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any causes that led to the weird behavior of the "Console" view described in the original post, but after *"[resetting](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-9j.htm)"* the perspective, the expected original behavior resumed.